# How can I add Time in Query? MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

hopefully someone can help me.
I want basically this.

```
SELECT * from T where diliverydate < (deadlineDate - some Days)
```

I tried

```
db.movie.find({$expr: { $lte: [ '$movie.firstdeliveryDate' , '$movie.deadlineDate' + 24*60*60 ]}})
```

```
db.movie.find({$expr: { $lte: [ '$movie.firstdeliveryDate' , {$add : ['$movie.deadlineDate', 3 * 24 * 60 * 60 ]} ]}})
```

Both dates are stored inside the movie object.

How can I add time to the second date?

I know this Query works:

```
db.movie.find({$expr: { $gte: [ '$movie.deliveryDate' ,  new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 1000 * 3600 * 24 * 90) ]}})
```

But I want to manipulate the date which is stored in the object.

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost got it at the second try. You did not multiply by 1,000 to convert to milliseconds and you used `$add` instead of `$subtract`

The exact semantic translation of `SELECT * from T where diliverydate < (deadlineDate - some Days)` would be

```
db.movie.find({
  $expr: {
    $lt: [ // $lt because of '>'
      '$movie.firstdeliveryDate' ,
      { $subtract : ['$movie.deadlineDate', 3 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 ] }
    ]
  }
})
```